# Show/Hide options in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I apologize for this dumb question. I have seen multiple answers with people getting this to work but I cannot get it for some reason.I have to dropdowns, 1 state and the other locations. I need the locations to be filtered when the user selects a state. I have this working fine in chrome on Mac. with the following code. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nunotmp/xt4dvj1n/)

I'll paste the code here as well.

HTML

```
<select id="states">
<option value="none">-- Select State --</option>
<option value="TX">Texas</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
</select>

<select id="locations">
<option value="none">-- Select Location --</option>
<option>123 Nowhere TX</option>
<option>123 Somewhere TX</option>
<option>123 Elsewhere AL</option>
<option>123 Where? AL</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#states').change( function() {
    var $root = $(this);
    var selectedState = $root.val();
    $('#locations').val('none');

    $('#locations option').each(function(){
        var location = $(this).text();
        var abbr = location.substr(location.length - 2);
        if ( abbr != selectedState ) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });

});
```

});

If anyone can help me getting this to work in IE I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer does not support hiding `options` from `select` element.

You can only disable or enable them like so:

`$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();`

`$(this).removeAttr('disabled').show();`

You can remove the options using `remove()` , and then re-add them. But it is more involved depending on how you create options in the first place. If it's a static list, it might be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Yes, this is a very long list of location and did go the disable route but the list was just too long. This list has over 160 locations that are pulled from a database.

Comment: It might be easier to populate the options as you select in the first combo box rather than hiding/showing. But it will require keeping the entire list in memory. Perhaps someone else will provide you with example.

Comment: Two examples: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xt4dvj1n/1/) works with existing markup while [that](http://jsfiddle.net/xt4dvj1n/3/) one avoids the need to initialize `select` with all options.